# UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nlsxbe in java.library.path

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I'm trying to create an external java application that can point to a folder of lotus notes files and get the earliest and latest dates for email.

The plan is create this using java and the notes.jar api.

This doesn't appear to be at all well documented and I think the first issue I have is getting eclipse to work with some of the example code. The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nlsxbe in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.load(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.checkLoaded(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.initThread(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Where am I going wrong? I added the notes.jar and NCSO.jar files as refernced libraries.

Comment: If your problem is that in eclipse it works and in a running jar it is not working, and throws that error, try to add nlsxbe folder location in your path, i.e. if it is in c:\lotus\domino: path=%path%;c:\lotus\domino\ and then to launch your jar with java -jar jarname.jar and you can also make a batch with this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Notes.jar, you must be running your code on a system with a valid installation of Lotus Notes client or Domino server code. That's where nlsxbe.dll comes from. Note that if you are running in a 64 bit JVM, your only option is to install Domino server code, because there is no 64 bit Notes client code. You may need to check with the managers of your Notes and Domino system, and possibly with your IBM representative to check on the licensing implications of this.

If you can't or don't want to instal Notes or Domino code on the system, then you can't use notes.jar, but you can still use NCSO.jar. You will have to make sure that your Domino servers have the IIOP task enabled for this. See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_pt1/index.html) (it's old, but still accurate AFAIK) for more info about the difference between using the local (notes.jar) and remote (NCSO.jar) access methods.